# event full/waitlist problem

Tags: civievent

I'm running CIVICRM (4.6.9) on a drupal 7 (current version) installation. I understand from my client (and I have not been able to duplicate this as it works fine at my end) that several of our participants are unable to complete registration (via Paypal) when they receive their email notification of being moved to "pending from waitlist." I'm trying to find out what participants are doing in case that may be the issue, but since it's consistent among 3 so far, am assuming the problem is real.

We don't use scripts or cron for this (or any other function in CIVICRM) - we change participants' status by editing it from within the participant listings.

Increasing the size of the allowable number of participants from 20 to 100, for example, does not change the "event full" status of an event either even though there are no where near that many registrants, regardless of status. Participants are still told the event is full and added to the waitlist when they register. Is this because there are still waitlist entries outstanding, or is it some sort of problem with CIVICRM?

Thanks!

Chris Hutcheson

Answer (score 3):

Increasing the maximum number of participants only takes effect if you run the "Update Participant Statuses" scheduled job. If you don't run this in a cron job, you need to do it manually after increasing the size. Be aware this also updates the waitlist and moves people from pending statuses, if applicable.

Answer (score 1):

I remember seeing this issue some years ago, back in CiviCRM 3.x days. At the time it was down to CiviCRM checking if there was anyone on waiting list. If there was then all subsequent registrations would be treated as going onto the waiting list. I thought this has been corrected but might be worth checking that - you should be able to reproduce on the demo site.

The second potential issue worth checking also is the pending setting on the event configuration although my suspicion is that the problem is down to having someone on the waiting list status and CiviCRM therefore treating all others in the same way.

Comment: Thanks for this. That was my thought as well, and it sort of makes sense to clear the wait list first. However, I think we resolved this as well in an earlier update to this site, so I'm surprised to see it back once again.

Comment: Yep, if I get some time I'll test the theory on the demo site and confirm the wait list status is the problem.

Comment: Thanks Parvez. I've tried deleting smarty templates, config.ids.ini and clearing all the caches and none of that is making a difference. I have a development site up here as well and will see if I can do anything with it.